# Unable to print value using jq with grep

Tags: shell, grep, jq

I'm using below jq statement with grep in my code to print a value.

```
jq '.Subnets[0].Tags' subnet.txt | grep -q "${add}usea1 internal us-east"
```

This works fine for some values however, few values need grep to be "${add}use* internal us-east", can i use asterisk so that  all my values can be printed.

I get error when i include asterisk. any suggestions?

Comment: recall that `*` in a regular expression means `*` zero or more of the preceding character and that `.` means any single character AND recall that `*` will be processed by the shell, unless it is quoted. you might get what you want with `... | grep -q "${add}use.* internal us-east"`. Good luck.

Comment: Add 4 spaces in from on code samples OR for multiline code, use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on selected text.

Answer (score 1):

You have not followed the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines, but  as @shellter pointed out, the problem description suggests you just have to use the proper (grep) regex:

```
grep -q "${add}use.* internal us-east"
```

However, since you are using jq in any case, it would probably be better to perform the filtering by extending the jq filter, for example as follows:

```
jq --arg add "$add" '
  .Subnets[0].Tags
  | select(test("\($add)use.* internal us-east"))
' subnet.txt
```